# Values from global pointer operated in a function in C is not preserved

Tags: c, pointers, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a global pointer declared as such `int * elements` and initialized as `elements = (int *)calloc(noOfElements,sizeOf(int))`

I have function which sorts the data in the elements as

```
void InsertionSort(int start, int size)
{
    int i,j,temp;
    for(i=start+1; i<size; i++)
    {
        temp = elements[i];
        for(j=i-1; j>=0&& elements[j]>temp; j--)
            elements[j+1] = elements[j];
        elements[j+1] = temp;
    }
}
```

at the end of the function the values in elements are

> value = {15, 21, 35, 49, 77, 83, 86, 86, 92, 93}

but the when the function returns to the main routine after the call the values in elements change

```
InsertionSort(completion, range);
```

> New value = {15, 21, 35, 49, 77, 83, 86, 86, ***6303760, 0***}

I been using GDB to trace this but I have no clue as to why it changes after the function executes.

For more clarity I'm trying to reference the elements to a `int **` using

`sections[i] = &elements[completion];`

after the function 'InsertionSort' completes execution

Here is a basic code of the full program with comments for clarity

```
            // Global Variables
            int noOfThreads;
            int noOfElements;
            char sortAlgo;
            int * elements;
            int range;
            int lastRange;

            void FillArray(){
                int i;
                for(i = 0;i < noOfElements; i++){
                    // Limiting random value range from 0 to 99
                    elements[i] = rand()%100;
                }
            }

            int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
                int **sections;
                int completion;
                /*
                * Basic argument checking conditions removed 
                */
                elements = (int *)calloc(noOfElements,sizeof(int));
                noOfElements = atoi(argv[1]);
                noOfThreads = atoi(argv[2]);
                sortAlgo = argv[3][0];
                // Calculate the size of each section to be separated from the elements array to be operate individually based on number of threads requested
                range = noOfElements / noOfThreads;
                // Calculate the size of the last section to be separated from the elements array to be operate individually 
                lastRange = range + (noOfElements % noOfThreads);

                sections = (int** )malloc(noOfThreads * sizeof(int*));
                for (int i = 0; i < noOfThreads-1; i++ )
                    sections[i] = (int* )calloc(range,sizeof(int));
                sections[noOfThreads-1] = (int* )calloc(lastRange,sizeof(int));

                // Fill the array with random values
                FillArray();

                completion=0;
                for (int i = 0; i < noOfThreads - 1; i++ )
                {
                        InsertionSort(completion, range);
                        sections[i] = &elements[completion];
                        completion = completion + range;
                }
                InsertionSort(completion, lastRange);
                sections[noOfThreads - 1] = &elements[completion];
                Merge(sections,elements);

            }
```

Comment: It seems unlikely that your issue is in the code you posted. Can you post a complete example that replicates your issue?

Comment: What is the value of `noOfElements` and what is the value of `range` passed to your function?

Comment: Why do you even have a global pointer variable? That is asking for trouble.

Comment: @stackptr in order to simplify the code. But I don't see as to how that should cause the problem that I'm facing. I am relatively new to pointer, dynamic memory allocation and call stack concepts.

Comment: You can't dereference pointers to another scope. If the pointer is global, you might accidentally dereference it when it points into nother scope.